# Apache solr process killed automatically

Tags: drupal, solr

I am using Apache Solr for one of my Drupal sites. I start my Apache Solr with Java -Jar -Xmx256M start.jar to fix the memory limit. I run my Apache in screen, but at times i see that my instance of Apache solr gets stopped/killed automatically. In my dev server i find it very hard to start it manually. Is there any fix to stop the instance getting killed automatically?

By the way the following are some of the warning i get in the console 
"solrconfig.xml:  is deprecated and no longer recommended used."
"WARNING:  and  configuration sections are deprecated (but still work). Please use  instead."

Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm Which Java are you using? Is it Java 7 update X

Comment: No what i meant was is it java 6 or java 7?

Comment: java version "1.6.0_31" this is what i get when i used java -version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem initially as well. I solved it by starting a screen session as root and starting Solr within that session. Also try adding a `nohup` before the java command and see if that works.

Comment: HI ansari, thanks for the reply. Ur answer solved my issue. Thanks a lot once again:):)

Comment: Ansari, I can't understand. please, u can tell me step-by-step commands for this process?

Comment: @DivyangShah Look up the "screen" command for Linux and how to start processes within a screen session, detach the screen, and leave them running.

Comment: @Ansari , hello, I have started screen session as a root. than started tomcat over screen session. But, it generates same problem. any idea?